# How does the following code go through a text file?

Tags: haskell, file-io

I'm having some trouble understanding a slice of code.

[In Real World Haskell Chapter 7](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html) in the section "Working With Files and Handles" the author uses the following piece of code to iterate through a text file and writing every line to a new text file in upper case: *(full credit to the author for this code)*

```
-- file: ch07/toupper-imp.hs
import System.IO
import Data.Char(toUpper)

main :: IO ()
main = do 
       inh <- openFile "input.txt" ReadMode
       outh <- openFile "output.txt" WriteMode
       mainloop inh outh
       hClose inh
       hClose outh

mainloop :: Handle -> Handle -> IO ()
mainloop inh outh = 
    do ineof <- hIsEOF inh
       if ineof
           then return ()
           else do inpStr <- hGetLine inh
                   hPutStrLn outh (map toUpper inpStr)
                   mainloop inh outh
```

The part I don't understand is: How does Haskell know which line to write to the other file?

From what I gather from the code the position in the input file never changes, so by my c-influenced logic, `mainloop` would be called again with the same input handle, and as such it would read the same line every time, never progressing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [handle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#t:Handle) that `openFile` returns is associated with a pointer to the current position in the file. From the docs:

> Most handles will also have a current I/O position indicating where the next input or output operation will occur.

Whenever you read a line from that handle via `hGetLine` this pointer will be advanced to the next line. IIRC that is the same behavior as with C file-handles.

Comment: You recall correctly; it's even the case with C++ stream objects, and that includes fstream.